# how to handle java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: due to invalid format fromapi response

Tags: java, android, datetime, datetime-parsing

```
String response = "20221124112443"
```

in this format data should come from API  but i don't know but from API some different format  response coming so i am getting below  error and app crash .

java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end -1, length 11

```
public void getCameraDateAndTime() {
                            Log.i("TAG", "onChanged: " + response);
                            String datetime = response.replace(";", "");
                            String mYear = datetime.substring(0, 4);
                            String mMonth = datetime.substring(4, 6);
                            String mDay = datetime.substring(6, 8);
                            Log.i("TAG", "onChanged: " + mYear + " " + mMonth + " " + mDay); }
```

can any one please help me how to handle this error so that app should not crash ,

Comment: What is `112443` at the end? I believe the month (11) and the day (24) have been repeated - is this correct? If yes, what is 43 at the end?

Comment: 24 is day ,11 is month  its hour , minute and second

Comment: What I would suggest to do is:

- If you are talking for the response of a Rest API then you can test the response with tools like Postman, if the response is changing then you should talk (or look the documentation) with the devs that wrote that API.
- If you are talking for just an Api from some library then I recommend to check the documentation, since probably every method has a documentation of the response.

Comment: The code you posted does not match with the error description. Currently, your response you posted is 14 length while the error saying 11. The start,end indexes are manually added and they are all > 0 (in the code) but the error saying start 0 and end -1. So either you 'created' the code just to post it and get ideas or you are executing another method/class/java file

Comment: I cannot reproduce. I get `onChanged: 20221124112443` and next `onChanged: 2022 11 24`. I too encourage you to use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter` for parsing the date and time, though.

Answer (score 2):

I do not recommend extracting date-time data from a `String` by using [`String#substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-). A date-time `String` should be parsed using the date-time API. You can get year, month, day, hour, minute etc. from the resulting object.

I recommend you use java.time API and put the processing (parsing and getting data from the parsed string) inside the `try/catch` block.

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String response = "20221124112443";
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMddHHmmss");
        try {
            LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(response, parser);
            System.out.println(ldt);
            System.out.printf("Year: %d, Month: %d, Day: %d", ldt.getYear(), ldt.getMonthValue(), ldt.getDayOfMonth());
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Wrong data"); // Replace it with Log.error
            // throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong data" + response); // Recommended so that it can be handled by the caller
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2022-11-24T11:24:43
Year: 2022, Month: 11, Day: 24
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: Thanks for answer ,but crash talks about String out Of bound exception  parsing logic is correct seems  i want handle with length of string can we do in that way ?

Comment: I do not recommend extracting date-time data from a `String` by using `String#substring`. A date-time string should be parsed using the date-time API. You can get year, month, day, hour, minute etc. from the resulting object.